# Can use openssl instead of Python RSA and Base64 algorithms?

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, rsa, pkcs#1

Can use the openssl command to implement equivalent functionality with Python RSA and Base64 algorithms?

For example, the RSA public key and the password to be encrypted are known. The Python algorithm is

```
ciphertext = base64.b64encode(PKCS1_v1_5.new(pubkey).encrypt(password.encode('utf-8')))
```

Suppose the password is 123456 and the public key is pubkey.pem. Is the following openssl command equivalent to the Python algorithm?

```
echo 123456 | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem -out ciphertext.txt | openssl enc -e -base64 -in ciphertext.txt -out r.txt
```

The result of r.txt is equivalent to the ciphertext of the Python algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - This appears to be a programming question, and programming questions are off-topic here even if they are about cryptography. The right home for programming questions is stackoverflow; I can migrate this there for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be, well, if and only if your password is "123456" of course.

The randomization that the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding performs will mean that the ciphertext is always different, of course.

To test: decrypt the ciphertext using the reverse operations and the private key in Python. For more certainty, decrypt using `openssl` as well.

Comment: And you use `echo -n` (on a version that supports it) to avoid adding a spurious newline. (And don't use Windows CMD, where `echo foo | something` actually echos f o o SP CR LF.)

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, it is the problem caused by Windows CMD. When replacing echo with -in, the problem is solved. Thank you again!